# Is Java's default value for Boolean 'true'?

Tags: java, boolean

Why does `private Boolean shouldDropTables;` assign `true` by default to the variable instead of `NULL`, like when writing `private Integer anInteger;`?

I am asking because I came across some code where there was an evaluation on a `shouldDropTables` Boolean variable being `NULL` or not determining whether to execute a method.

Comment: "Why does private Boolean shouldDropTables; assign true by default to the variable instead of NULL" It does not. Some other code is needed for that, which is not shown in this question.

Comment: The answers here are good but there is no context and wrong assumptions. This question is not on topic for SO

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Boolean (with a uppercase 'B') is a Boolean object, which if not assigned a value, will default to null.  boolean (with a lowercase 'b') is a boolean primitive, which if not assigned a value, will default to false.

```
Boolean objectBoolean;
boolean primitiveBoolean;

System.out.println(objectBoolean); // will print 'null'
System.out.println(primitiveBoolean); // will print 'false'
```

Answer (score 12):

**No.**

Boolean is `null` by default.

Answer (score 5):

It's NULL by default. Because it's a Boolean Object.

```
Object 'Boolean' =  NULL value          // By default,
Primitive type 'boolean' = false value  // By default.
```

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to add one point (for beginners) regarding a primitive `boolean` variable.

As @99tm answered, the default value is "false". This is correct for instance or class variables.

If you have a method local variable (i.e. local to a method) as a primitive `boolean`, there is no default value and it is not an `Object` so it also cannot be null.

You must initialize it before using it, otherwise it's a compilation error.

Comment: I never knew that about primitives. Now I'll have to look up what `int` and `double` are initialized to when instance variables.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're not seeing some initialization.

It has null by default. See this sample:

```
$ cat B.java
class B {
        private Boolean shouldDrop;
        public static void main( String ... args ) {
                System.out.println( new B().shouldDrop );
        }
}

$ javac B.java

$ java B
null
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

[JLS 9, 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

> - For type boolean, the default value is false.
> - For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.

`Boolean` is a reference type, therefore the default value is `null`.