# try- catch, loop, and failed display of information

Tags: java, loops, try-catch

When I enter a value that is in between than -2147483648 and 2147483647, the program closes and does not display the valid number like I wrote. If I enter a number outside the range, it is supposed to enter a while loop until I enter a valid number between the range. However when I enter a number outside the range it simply displays an exception error, which is why I put the catch there in the 1st place.

I have tried this problem for a few hours now, I am still relatively new to coding (2nd class) so I am sorry if this has been answered before. I looked up a lot of the older answers and tried to use that as a model for my code. However this is as far as I got.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws NumberFormatException
    {
        String input;
        boolean x;
        int number;

        while (x = false)
        {
            try
            {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer: ");      //creates input box for user to enter integer value
                number = Integer.parseInt(input);

                if ( number < -2147483648 && number > 2147483647)

                    x = false;

                else
                {
                    x = true;
                    System.out.println("You entered: " + number);
                }

                break;
            }

            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                continue;
            }
       }

   }

}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `=` and `==`?

Comment: it should be just while(!x) ...

Comment: boolean x; has not been initialized ?!!

Comment: Also, try using a debugger.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` is probably not the best method to use, in cases where the input might legitimately lie outside of the range of valid `int` values.  A useful answer to this question would have you use a different method for your parsing.

Comment: @KickButtowski default boolean are false

Comment: Local variables do not have a default value.

Comment: @wrongAnswer it does not matter. you have to initialized it anyway

Comment: @Voicu please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/6048333/1085186

Comment: @wrongAnswer - feel free to try it for yourself.  Voicu is right.  The question that you've linked isn't about local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition can never evaluate to `true`. Along with changing the `while` to

```
while (x == false)
```

as others have suggested, you also need to change the `if` statement from an `AND` to an `OR`:

```
if ( number < -2147483648 || number > 2147483647)
```

Also, you don't need a `break` statement after the `else` block. Since you are setting `x` to `true`, you will break out of the loop anyway. The way you have it now, you are breaking out of the loop on the first iteration.

Additionally, you should be initializing `boolean x` to `false`. At the top, you should have:

`boolean x = false;` where you have `boolean x;`

So when all that is said and done:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws NumberFormatException
    {
        String input;
        boolean x = false;
        int number;

        while (x == false)
        {
            try
            {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer: ");      //creates input box for user to enter integer value
                number = Integer.parseInt(input);

                if ( number < -2147483648 || number > 2147483647)
                {
                    x = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    x = true;
                    System.out.println("You entered: " + number);
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                continue;
            }
       }
   }
}
```

And further cleaning it up. The `parseInt` throws an exception when the number is outside the desired range, and we're going into the `catch` block. So all you really need is:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws NumberFormatException
    {
        String input;
        int number;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer: ");      //creates input box for user to enter integer value
                number = Integer.parseInt(input);

                System.out.println("You entered: " + number);
                break;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                // do nothing
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: By default boolean are false if not initialized.

Comment: Yes but, especially for a beginner, it's much better to be explicit rather than implicit.

Comment: Yes but that is not the problem it can be a suggestion for good practice. Also you don't need to set false every time you can just set true in negation condition ... Please check the edit for the correct negation !

Comment: It was a suggestion. I said you "should be" initializing it to false.

Comment: isn't the range int -2147483648 to 2147483647?

Answer (score 0):

First I did this

```
 while (x = false)    =>
 while (x == false)
```

Then Eclipse reminds that the `boolean x` is not initialized.  As some of others pointed out, You can use other way like while(!x) but this the reason it fails.

Then, if ( number < -2147483648 && number > 2147483647) will always be false because it's int and the comparison is inverted.

Here is the full code after fix:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyTextPanel
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws NumberFormatException
    {
        String input;
        long number;

        while (true) {
            try {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer: ");      //creates input box for user to enter integer value
                number = Long.parseLong(input);

                if ( number < -2147483648 || number > 2147483647)
                    continue;

                else  {
                    System.out.println("You entered: " + number);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e)  {
                continue;
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This was one issue, however it did not help with the compilation of my code in the way I wanted. The println still is not visible, and numbers outside the loop still do not enter the loop as they should

Comment: @MatthewOsman, what is the range that you want to print and exit?

Answer (score 0):

How can a number be less than a negative number and greater than a positive number at the same time?

```
if ( number < -2147483648 && number > 2147483647)
```

change it to `||`

Also I suggest that rather than using `magic numbers`, use `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Also as you are catching the `NumberFormatException` you should not also declare this as being thrown from `main`

Comment: i<10 && i>1 is a valid condition !!! im not saying his condition is valid but this should ans 'How can a number be less that something and greater than something at the same time?'